# How to enter symbols and align equations

Tags: pdf, r, rmarkdown, rstudio, tinytex

1)I wrote an equation and when I hover my mouse over it it shows perfectly as I want it to but when I am knitting to pdf I get the error 1 :

[image: Error 1]

Code used for error1:

[image]

```
 $var(u_{t}) = {\delta}_{u}^2 < \infty $
```

2)I have three equations which I want to center and align one underneath the other. When I knit to pdf i get the error 2:

[image: Error 2]

Code used for error 2:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
$z_{t} & = [(w_{t}/10)^{0.2}]e^t$ \\
$ln(z_{t}) & = 0.2ln(w_{t}/10) + ln(e_{t})$ \\
$y_t & = -0.2ln(10) + 0.2x_{t} + u_{t}$
\end{align*}
```

I also tried to write {latex} in the chunk to fix the issue

I also already loaded packages tidyverse and tinytex.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: the first one with `\delta` needs to be in math mode so `$\{\delta....`  the second one `align*` starts math mode so remove all the `$` inside it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your help! It worked perfectly! I have been struggling with this since yesterday

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was improper application of `$` signs to enter and leave math, as noted in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The first one with `\delta` needs to be in math mode so `$\{\delta....`.

The second one, `align*` starts math mode so remove all the `$` inside it.